# IndexError: list index out of range when running mask-rcnn?

Tags: python, range

I'm trying to run a segment prediction on some images using ***Mask R-CNN*** , the only thing is that , the code that i'm using has been written taking in consideration the COCO Weights , i've modified it , so i can run my prediction using a fashion datasets , so different classes , different weights .....ect

Here's the Code :

```
 # load the class label names from disk, one label per line
   CLASS_NAMES = open(args["labels"]).read().strip().split("\n")

 # generate random (but visually distinct) colors for each class label
 # (thanks to Matterport Mask R-CNN for the method!)
   hsv = [(i / len(CLASS_NAMES), 1, 1.0) for i in range(len(CLASS_NAMES))]
   COLORS = list(map(lambda c: colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(*c), hsv))
   random.seed(42)
   random.shuffle(COLORS)

   class SimpleConfig(Config):
       # give the configuration a recognizable name
          NAME = "fashion"

       # set the number of GPUs to use along with the number of images
       # per GPU
          GPU_COUNT = 1
          IMAGES_PER_GPU = 1

   # number of classes (we would normally add +1 for the background
   # but the background class is *already* included in the class
   # names)
          NUM_CLASSES = 1 + 3

   # initialize the inference configuration
     config = SimpleConfig()

   # initialize the Mask R-CNN model for inference and then load the
   # weights
     print("[INFO] loading Mask R-CNN model...")
     model = modellib.MaskRCNN(mode="inference", config=config,
     model_dir=os.getcwd())
     model.load_weights(args["weights"], by_name=True)

   # load the input image, convert it from BGR to RGB channel
   # ordering, and resize the image
   # default value 512 form the width
     image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
     image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
     image = imutils.resize(image, width=1150)

   # perform a forward pass of the network to obtain the results
     print("[INFO] making predictions with Mask R-CNN...")
     r = model.detect([image], verbose=1)[0]

   # loop over of the detected object's bounding boxes and masks
     for i in range(0, r["rois"].shape[0]):
        # extract the class ID and mask for the current detection, then
        # grab the color to visualize the mask (in BGR format)
         classID = r["class_ids"][i]
         mask = r["masks"][:, :, i]
        # by default : color = COLORS[classID][::-1]
         color = COLORS[classID][::-1]

   # visualize the pixel-wise mask of the object
     image = visualize.apply_mask(image, mask, color, alpha=0.5)
   # convert the image back to BGR so we can use OpenCV's drawing
   # functions
     image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

   # loop over the predicted scores and class labels
     for i in range(0, len(r["scores"])):
   # extract the bounding box information, class ID, label, predicted
   # probability, and visualization color
         (startY, startX, endY, endX) = r["rois"][i]
         classID = r["class_ids"][i]
         label = CLASS_NAMES[classID]
         score = r["scores"][i]
         color = [int(c) for c in np.array(COLORS[classID]) * 255]

   # draw the bounding box, class label, and score of the object
         cv2.rectangle(image, (startX, startY), (endX, endY), color, 2)
         text = "{}: {:.3f}".format(label, score)
         y = startY - 10 if startY - 10 > 10 else startY + 10
         cv2.putText(image, text, (startX, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
         0.6, color, 2)

   # show the output image
     cv2.imshow("Output", image)
     cv2.waitKey()
```

And This Is The Error That I get , When Running The Above Code :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "maskrcnn_fashion_predict.py", line 78, in <module>
        color = COLORS[classID][::-1]
    IndexError: list index out of range
```

Any Suggstion On That Can Be Solved Would Be Great Thank You All.

Comment: can you print `classID` in your loop and `COLORS` list value

Comment: this is what i get , when i do print(classID) in my loop :                                               2                                                                                                                                 2                                                                                                                                  2                                                                                                                                 3